# Android Studio Doesn't Work even after finding the JDK

Tags: android-studio

After installing Android Studio and **solving** the "unable to find JDK file" problem, When I click on Android Studio it opens up for less than a second and closes rights away, as if nothing happens. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

**Windows 7**

**Android Studio 2.1**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my installation.

It might not work for you, but uninstalling and reinstalling the application fixed the problem for me.